# Dynamically extract string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column called 'cArticle' in excel, containing data in below format. I have a requirement to extract in another column the code that is in brackets. Ex- Z1A,F5C,etc

| cArticle |
| --- |
| Molecular Dispersion (Z1A) |
| Acrona Perse (F5C) |
| Leco Spers (HLP) |
| Cullar Dipters (LPP) |

I have managed to get it partially working by using the below formula, but it still returns with values with the closing brackets. How can I modify it to get the desired results?

RIGHT(cArticle,4)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE(your_formula,")","")`

Comment: Is the code you need always at the end of the value? And is it always 3 characters  long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string always ends with `(XXX)` and the content in the brackets is always 3 digit. You can also try:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(cArticle,4),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **code** is always at the farthest right and is only 3 characters long, you can use formula as below

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(cArticle,4),")","")
```

However if your **code** is not always at the farthest right and may be more or less than 3 characters than you can use formula below, which will work in all cases even if there is no **code** present

```
=IFERROR(MID(cArticle,FIND("(",cArticle)+1,FIND(")",cArticle)-FIND("(",cArticle)-1),"No Code")
```

[image: sample1]